# Make cordova android app expire after 30 days

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

Im trying to set an expiry time in my cordova app that will force close the app or allow me to display a page with a custom message.

Comment: I think the best way to implement it is by using a remote server check every time the app starts , you check the app current app version from gradle buildConfig class and compare it to the latest one on your remote server, if there any new version show a blocking dialog fragment redirecting to update the app

Answer (score 1):

With the help of  localStorage .

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
    if (typeof window.localStorage.getItem('someKey') === 'undefined'){
        window.localStorage.setItem('someKey', new Date() );
    }else{
        var current = new Date().getTime();
        if(current > ( window.localStorage.getItem('someKey') + 2592000 ) ){
           ///  Expired
        }
    }
});
```